# Turn off auto brightness in iOS

Tags: objective-c, iphone-privateapi, brightness, uiscreen

Auto brightness overrides screen brightness value which I have set for my application. I set brightness by

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:0.1];
```

I want to turn off auto brightness programatically

I am developing enterprise app so there is no issue for using private api

I tried with `UIScreenBrightnessDidChangeNotification` but its not update my value

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [center addObserverForName:UIScreenBrightnessDidChangeNotification
                        object:nil
                         queue:nil
                    usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification)
     {
         NSLog(@"Brightness changed: %f", [[UIScreen mainScreen] brightness]);
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:0.1];
         });
     }];
}
```

Comment: I've copy pasted your notification code into an Obj-C app of mine and it's working fine (on an iPhone 8 running iOS 11). Print `mainScreen`'s `brightness` after you've set it; what does that show?

Comment: @meaning-matters - thanks for your support. In my case its not work. My device have 0.5(50%) brightness when I run app. than I Programatically sets 0.1(10%) brightness on button click event and its should remain same but brightness will change and even with above code it will not stick to 0.1(10%) brightness. It will change after few sec or I move my device around. I am using iPhone X with iOS 12.1

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the [brightnessDidChangeNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/1617832-brightnessdidchangenotification) and set the brightness back where you want it in your handler.

Of course you also need to add code to check the brightness after the app has been in background (and may have missed notification(s)).

Comment: Already try this but it not works. I get trigger in block but not updated with my value.

Comment: @Shreyank Please show that code/attempt in your Question.